# Getting value for keys inside nested arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

An example:

```
$result = [];
foreach($ret as $item) {
    $result[] = $item['id'];
}
return $result;
```

Is there a one-liner in PHP that can do this? It very hard to search on google for "keys in arrays" because it's very vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5.0 required for `array_column`:

```
$result = array_column($ret, 'id');
```

Other than that your loop is as good as it gets.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I wanted ... but we are running on PHP 5.4 still :(